# Variable ora (time) with blank

Tags: windows, time, batch-file, variable-assignment

The following assignment:

> set ora=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%

returns the value " 9194234" when the time is 9.19.42,34.

How can be squeezed the value or better to have the value "09194234"?

Comment: Actually I dont understand your question. I just guess, do you want the return value get preceded by 0, if so, why not just `set ora=0%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%`

Comment: What I mean is that the value is " 9194234" with an initial blank, I would to take the value of blank out, so that I can have "9194234" or "09194234". This assignment is done automatically and I wouldn't like to have a variable with an initial blank that can cause some trouble to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
set ora=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
set ora=%ora: =0%
```

It replaces spaces with 0

Comment: Its considered polite to mark the answer as accepted answer and as useful, then I get some stackOverflow goody points and my life feel slightly less pointless.

Comment: Done, the power is in the little things